# Chromatic Number of Trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

All trees with more than one vertex have the same chromatic number. What is it & Why?

(Is this chromatic number by any chance 2, by definition of what a tree is? Since a tree is acyclic and connected, I think it would have a chromatic number that is strictly one less than 3, which is what a cycle would have to have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trees are bipartite graphs so you can always color them properly with two colors.